# Keep a connection open in Java

Tags: java

My code creates a connection to the docker, sends a command and reads the output.

The problem is that the connection dies and when I run it again, I basically create another connection, send data, read data, etc...

**But I need to keep this connection open** so I can send commands and read the result using the `buffers out, err` without losing the flow of my commands. Any idea how to do this?

```
public static String getDockerConsole(String containerName, String input) {
    String[] cmd = new String[]{
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            input
    };
    DockerClient dockerClient = dockerClient();
    Container container = getContainer(containerName);
    ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateCmdResponse = dockerClient.execCreateCmd(container.getId()).withAttachStdout(true).withTty(true).withAttachStderr(true).withCmd(cmd).withUser("root").exec();
    ByteArrayOutputStream  out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream err = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        dockerClient.execStartCmd(container.getId()).withExecId(execCreateCmdResponse.getId()).withDetach(false).withTty(true).exec(new ExecStartResultCallback(out, err)).awaitCompletion();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return out.toString() + err.toString();
}
```

EDIT: When I send a command to execute a file, it shows the file in the debugg section and hangs in `awaitCompletion()`. I want to access this connection so I can show the data externally

Comment: You should open a connection, use it, and close it in the narrowest scope possible.  You shouldn't keep a connection open that way.

Comment: The problem is that when i execute a file the process goes to background and hangs in awaitCompletion. I want to access this data